# Getting instance of an object using class name string

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create an object from the fully qualified object name string.
Using approach bellow I'm getting null from the GetInstance method.

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
namespace MyApp.Domain.Cars;

public static class Features
{
    public class CarPainted
    {
        public Guid CarId { get; set; }
        ...        
    }
}

string fqn = "MyApp.Domain.Cars.Features.CarPainted";

var carPaintedObject = GetInstance(fqn); //always null

private static object GetInstance(string strFullyQualifiedName)
{
   Type type = Type.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
   if (type != null)
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
   {
      type = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
      if (type != null)
         return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   }
}
```

Comment: What part of your code runs in this case? Is the type `null` after `GetType`?

Comment: The fully-qualified name of your class isn't "MyApp.Domain.Cars.Features.CarPainted", it's "MyApp.Domain.Cars.Features+CarPainted". Nested classes are represented using a `+` separator, not `.`